# Adding a minimal `pyproject.toml` silently breaks my build

Tags: cmake, setuptools, python-packaging, pybind11, scikit-build

I am trying to use `pybind11` and `scikit-build` in a minimal repository based on [their cpp example repo](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build-sample-projects/tree/master/projects/hello-cpp). When trying to build it via `pip install -e .`, pip claims that the file was "Successfully installed", but didn't actually build anything (I suspect it never even ran the `setup` function inside `setup.py`). I can confirm it doesn't work given the error message `ImportError: cannot import name 'example' from 'hello'` when attempting to use the module.

Interestingly enough, the project works when I either

1. run `python setup.py develop` directly (thus bypassing `pyproject.toml`, pressumably). For this, I installed `setuptools`, `scikit-build`, `cmake`, `pybind11`, and `ninja` to their appropriate version through `conda install X`.
2. Deleting `pyproject.toml`, relying on pre-installed build-time dependencies.

I don't see how my `pyproject.toml` file would be problematic. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

My project layout is

```
hello-cpp
├── hello
|    └── __init__.py (empty)
|    └── hello.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
```

setup.py:

```
from skbuild import setup

setup(
name="hello-cpp",
    version="1.2.3",
    description="a minimal example package (cpp version)",
    author="Me",
    license="MIT",
    packages=["hello"],
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.22)

project(hello)

find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)

pybind11_add_module(example hello/hello.cpp)
install(TARGETS example LIBRARY DESTINATION hello)
```

pyproject.toml (I'll note that the problem persists even without constraining versions here):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools==65.6.3", 
      "scikit-build==0.15.0", 
      "cmake>=3.18", 
      "pybind11==2.9.1",
      "ninja"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

src/hello.cpp:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}
```

I'm trying this in Ubuntu 20.

EDIT:
I am attempting to build this in a `conda` environment that has no packages other than python=3.10 (and whatever packages are bundled by default) installed. I've also tried it after `conda install`ing the packages mentioned above.

The python script that fails with the `ImportError` upon adding `pyproject.toml` is

```
python -c "from hello import example"
```

Comment: Try `python -m pip install --editable .` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- Are you using a Python virtual environment? Or a conda environment?

Comment: I get the same behavior with `python -m pip install --editable .` than I do with `pip install -e .`
I am using a conda environment

Comment: Maybe edit your question to clarify that you are using conda environments. It might also be interesting to see which code leads to the *import error*, because the code doing the import itself might also be the reason why it fails.

Comment: Sure thing! I made edits at the end adding this information

Comment: Can you do `python -c 'import hello; dir(hello)'`?

Comment: Sure, this is the output:
`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

Comment: OK. Seems like `hello` can be imported, but there is nothing usable in it, or at least no `hello.example`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I copied your files into a directory and tried this:

```
$ virtualenv .venv
$ .venv/bin/pip install .
$ ls .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hello
__init__.py                    __pycache__/                   example.cpython-311-darwin.so*
```

And it seems fine. Note that setuptools + CMake custom extension, scikit-build, and scikit-build-core all do not support editable installs (`-e`/`--editable`) since Setuptools 64. If you force the old implementation, it might sort-of work, but really isn't ideal still - you aren't getting much "editable" out of it. Scikit-build-core will have a proper editable installation mechanism soon (within a month or two).